# Facebook api graph v2.4 get simple data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

it is possible to get group post with graph v2.4 ?
cause i can't get anything with it , can't get post infos , can't comment .. nothing

in the other versions everything works great

and unfortunately the access token generated from the apps can only work with v2.4

i'm doing a cron job for that i have to use the app to refresh access token so i'm forced to use 2.4 , any solution for this ?

here's what i tried to do :

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=id_of_my_group_post&version=v2.4
```

Getting this error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "No node specified",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

if i changed : `&version=v2.4` to any other version it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your code snippet you are using Facebook Query Language (FQL). However, you need to be aware that this framework is NOT supported in Graph API v2.4. In fact, Facebook announced it will be only supported up to version 2.0. See quote below from the [Reference Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)...

> Version 2.0 of the Facebook Platform API is the last version where FQL will be available. Versions after 2.0 will not support FQL. Please migrate your applications to use Graph API instead of FQL. Please see our changelog for current version information.

Comment: sorry it's just for the demonstation i'm using api graph http , i only need the right way to do so , i updated the question